# Prioritizing attribute in Sparql query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This is a question about Sparql and Wikidata.
I want to formulate a query that returns an instance-type relation, but if it's not available return its sub-class. I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?ent_type  WHERE { 

 { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31 ?instanceof . } UNION 
 { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31/wdt:P279? ?subclass .  } UNION 
 { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P279* ?subclass  . } 

 BIND ( IF (BOUND (?instanceof), ?instanceof, ?subclass ) as ?ent_type  )
```

But unfortunately this returns all solutions, whereas I only want one solution

```
ent_type
----------
wd:Q811979
wd:Q386724
wd:Q811430
wd:Q7696957
```

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**coalesce**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-coalesce) to achieve this:

```sql
select distinct ?ent_type where { 
  optional { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31 ?direct }
  optional { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31/wdt:P279? ?indirect }
  optional { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P279* ?ancestor }
  bind(coalesce(?direct, ?indirect, ?ancestor) as ?ent_type)
}
```

Comment: Union and optional don't, in general, do the same thing.  Union says "each row will have bindings provided by one of these patterns".  Optional says "if bindings are available for this pattern, then include them in the row".  If there are possible values for ?direct, ?indirect, and ?ancestor, you want them all in the same row, so that you can choose between them, not in three separate rows.  If you want to prefer values for `wdt:P31/wdt:P279?` over `wdt:P279*`, then you need a way to distinguish them (e.g., by using different variables) so that you can pick between them.

Comment: So, I used three different variables and **optional**. It's not about speed.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify Joshua's answer, you don't actually need the coalesce:

```
select distinct ?ent_type where { 
  optional { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31 ?ent_typee . }
  optional { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31/wdt:P279? ?ent_type . }
  optional { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P279* ?ent_type . }
}
```

If there are multiple optionals with the same variable name (here `?ent_type`), the first "successful" one will bind the variable.

However, there seems to be a problem with your query logic: if there is no value for `wdt:P31`, then neither is there for `wdt:P31/wdt:P279?`, so there will never be a situation where the middle condition is met. Also, `wdt:P279*` will (because of the `*`) return the resource itself (`wd:Q7696957`) if there is no value for `wdt:P279` (which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: Agree. My original query looks a bit different. I have to include the entire query to describe the problem.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ?ent_type   {   
        { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31 ?instanceof . ?candidate1 owl:equivalentClass ?instanceof . } UNION 
   { wd:Q7696957 wdt:P31/wdt:P279? ?subclass1 . ?candidate2 owl:equivalentClass ?subclass1 . } UNION    
{ wd:Q7696957 wdt:P279* ?subclass2 . ?candidate3 owl:equivalentClass ?subclass2 . } 
   BIND( coalesce( ?candidate1, ?candidate2, ?candidate3 ) as ?ent_type )   }
In other words, find a mapping of its instance, it no mapping available for that, try a subclass there of and finally search for mappings of the subclass